# How to fetch "@microsoft.graph.downloadUrl" from Microsoft Search API?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am using Microsoft Search API to search for files in SharePoint, objective is to fetch temporary url ("@microsoft.graph.downloadUrl") amoung other fields.  I have used below search request,

```
Url - POST request: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/search/query
Body:
{
    "requests": [
        {
            "entityTypes": [
                "driveItem"
            ],
            "query": {
                "queryString": "search-value",
                "query": "path:\"https://{company}.sharepoint.com/sites/{site}/shared\""
            },          
            "fields": [
                "name",
                "webUrl",
                "@microsoft.graph.downloadUrl"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The result returned is below, and it is missing "@microsoft.graph.downloadUrl" field.

```
 "moreResultsAvailable": false,
    "hits": [
        {
            "hitId": "01CDLPULQVGFRNVHYTJVFL3NPPXIGOUDUS",
            "rank": 1,
            "summary": "string;#<c0>search-value</c0> <c0>search-value</c0> Internal 1 0 search-value Graph explorer {DA623115<ddd/>",
            "resource": {
                "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.driveItem",
                "name": "word.docx",
                "webUrl": "https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/{site}/Cases/search-value/word.docx"
            }
        },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search API can retrieve only properties but not instance attributes like "@microsoft.graph.downloadUrl".

[Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/search-concept-files#example-6-specify-select-properties)

[Instance attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/driveitem?view=graph-rest-1.0#instance-attributes)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.  I guess the alternative is to retrieve this information in a subsequent api call.  I was wondering if it is possible to achieve this using direct SharePoint Search API, i would like to avoid multiple calls (if possible).

Comment: I would use the subsequent call to get download link. I'm not familiar with SharePoint Search API.

Comment: you may want to [try the following REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/?view=odsp-graph-online) and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's no need to use the REST API. To get the temporary @microsoft.graph.downloadUrl download link I used the following to get the value:

```
var selectedFile = files.value[0];
var downloadLink = selectedFile["@microsoft.graph.downloadUrl"];
```

Found at this link: https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-api-docs/issues/547

I hope this helps